# Randomly selecting from a range of svg's

Tags: jquery

I've been working on a little xmas card - a simple and quick project but I can't get it to work properly.

For some reason I can't get it to select just a couple leaves :( - any quick thoughts?

I think the problem is

```
    var randomElements = $(shuffle($all).slice(0, $("input").val()));
$(randomElements).each(function() {
    $(this).animate({'opacity': 1}, 2000, ).animate({'opacity': 0.5}, 1000, );
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kickn/qhdsfkbc/1/

Answer (score 0):

Your `$all` is missing the class selector (`.`)

Instead of

```
var $all = $("st1")
```

it should be

```
var $all = $(".st1")
```

Additionally you're trying to retrieve a value `input`element, which doesn't exist. If you replace this for a number, then a number of leaves lights up. Your code would look then as follows:

```
var randomElements = $(shuffle($all).slice(0, 3));
    $(randomElements).each(function() {
        $(this).animate({'opacity': 1}, 2000, ).animate({'opacity': 0.5}, 1000, );
    });
```

I changed `$("input").val()` to `3`.

Comment: Thanks - changed that but then the whole tree is flashing instead of just a couple branches. I'm trying to use the slice to just select a couple of them :(

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Can you update your jsFiddle to match the question you're asking? It starts with a `sparkle` function, which tries to get a value from an HTML input element. But that input element does not exist in your HTML...

Comment: Sorry - should be there. the class is "st1" of the svg

Comment: Edited my question. Just a number of leaves lights up with the addition

Comment: Thanks - hugely appreciated! Now I just have to get them to move in parallel :)

Comment: You're welcome :-) I assume your original question ("select just a couple leaves") is answered with the addition? If so, please mark my answer as 'accepted'. If you need any help on a next challenge, I propose you post a new question.